# Meteor's iron:router loadingTemplate not rendered

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have the following code:

```
Router.configure({
        layoutTemplate: 'commonTemplate',
        loadingTemplate: 'loadingApp'
    });

Router.route('/configuration', {
    name:'configuration',
    template:'configuration',
    onBeforeAction: function(){
        this.layout(null);
        if (Session.get('appReady')){
            this.next();
        } else {
            console.log("loading app...");
            this.render('loadingApp');
        }
    }
});
```

"**loading app...**" is correctly shown on console.
However during that time (waiting for session variable), no loading template (neither from Router.configure; nor from this.render) is displayed.
Also when the session variable is true, the **configuration** template is rendered correctly.

Is this an *iron:router* bug or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Which versión of Meteor and Iron router are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working for me, maybe the problem is that your loading template isn't showing the loading content properly. I tested the code with the loading template from the https://atmospherejs.com/sacha/spin package and worked fine.

You could install from atmospherejs  the package sacha:spin and configure Iron Router to use the loading template, this package is easy to use, you have to use the template 'loading' where you want the loading animation.

1) `meteor add sacha:spin`

2) In your router file :

```
Router.configure({
  loadingTemplate: 'loading'
});

Router.route('/test', {
    name: 'test',
    template: 'test',
    onBeforeAction : function()
    {
      this.layout(null);
      if (Session.get('appReady')){
            this.next();
        } else {
            console.log("loading app...");
            this.render('loading');
        }
    }
  }
);
```